# How do I fix this formula?

Tags: java

I just started learning Java. I am currently writing basic code for a platform game, and I am having a problem with a formula that calculates the final `y` position of a character in the platform game.

The formula that I am trying to code is

```
y = y0 + vy * t - ( 1/2 * g * t^2)
```

where,
y = the final `y` position;
y0 = the initial `y` position;
vy = velocity along `y`-axis;
g = gravity;
t = time;

Below is the code that I wrote for this formula. (PLEASE IGNORE THE CODES FOR xPosition)

```
public class Position {

static double xPosition;
static double yPosition;
final static double gravity = 10.0; //gravity on Earth rounded up to the tens place.

public static double xPosition ( double initialPosition , double xVelocity , double time ) {
    return initialPosition + xVelocity * time;
}
public static double yPosition ( double initialPosition , double yVelocity , double time ) {
    return initialPosition + ( yVelocity * time ) - ( 0.5 * gravity * time * time );
}
```

That's the code. And, as shown below, I plugged in random values to try to check whether this formula works properly or not.

```
public static void main ( String args[] ) {
    xPosition = xPosition ( 5 , 4 , 9 );
    System.out.println ( xPosition );        
    yPosition = xPosition ( 0 , 10 , 5 );
    System.out.println ( yPosition );
}
```

When I compiled and ran this code, I got `50.0`. The problem is when I solved this by hand, I got `-75`. Is there something wrong with my code, or is it just a brain malfunction due to overworking myself? Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.


Comment: @Benjamin. Oh God. I hate it when I make a mistake like this. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: avoid using identical names for your method and variables. It will save you some future headaches.

Comment: @Lai. Yes. I will take note of your advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling the `xPosition ()` method twice.

Simply change

```
yPosition = xPosition ( 0 , 10 , 5 );
```

to

```
yPosition = yPosition ( 0 , 10 , 5 );
```

Comment: Thanks! You pointed out the error that I have been looking for the last 10 minutes.